# How to store utl_http.req object in database oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to store http request to reuse it when retrying to call a WEB SERVICE.
I tried to store the fields separately but I only found this :

```
TYPE req IS RECORD (
url                    VARCHAR2(32767 byte), -- Requested URL
method                 VARCHAR2(64),    -- Requested method
http_version           VARCHAR2(64),    -- Requested HTTP version
private_hndl           PLS_INTEGER      -- For internal use only);
```

is there a way to convert it to blob and then from blob to utl_http.req ?

Comment: do you want to convert your request or your response to blob? i see no need to convert your request to blob. your response instead could be some soap xml which you might want to convert

Comment: It's the request I want to convert because I won't have access to inputs when retrying the call also the request won't change so I don't need to reconstitute it everytime I call the WS.

Answer (score 0):

Create a normal table with se same structure as the req record but with the url as clob (+ some extra columns to identify the request, i.e. date, comment, name) :

```
CREATE TABLE t_http_req(
  url                    CLOB,
  method                 VARCHAR2(64),
  http_version           VARCHAR2(64),
  private_hndl           NUMBER
);
```

Inserts into t_http_req should use to_clob(req.url) to convert vc2 to clob.

```
INSERT INTO t_http_req(url, method, http_version, private_hndl)
VALUES(to_clob(req.url), req.method, req.http_version, req.private_handle);
```

Later you should be able to load a request row from the table and fill the values for the req record.

Comment: thx but Actually I wanted to store the header and content too otherwise it's not interesting...I don't know where are the header and body stored ? I don't understand what utl_http.set_header and utl_http.write_text do

Comment: The package utl_http provides various methods to get and set the data structures you are looking for. Search for the utl_http PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference regarding your Oracle-Version. Read the sections HTTP Requests and HTTP Responses. Then search for code examples for your use case (get/put,soap/rest).